# Django 1.7 migration can't find app

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm getting an error when running a migration changing a field from a CharField to a ManyToMany field.

I have a custom user model which chooses their interests, which I have greatly reduced for simplicity's sake.

```
# main.models
class Interest(models.Model):
    """
    get what the user is interested in.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


# accounts.models
from main.models import Interest

class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    the custom user class we are using
    """
    # before it was:
    # interests = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interest, blank=True, null=True,
        help_text="What are your interests or hobbies?")


# migration.py
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0009_remove_user_friends'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='interests',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(help_text='What are your interests or hobbies?', to='main.Interest', null=True, blank=True),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
    ]
```

The main app is installed correctly in `INSTALLED_APPS`, the dependencies are there, and I haven't had any migration problems up until now (9th migration within the accounts app).

Here is the stack trace. It appears it is having problems with `to='main.Interest'` in the migration file, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing that?

```
Applying accounts.0010_auto_20150309_1554...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 148, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'main'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 84, in render
    model = self.apps.get_model(lookup_model[0], lookup_model[1])
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 202, in get_model
    return self.get_app_config(app_label).get_model(model_name.lower())
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 150, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError("No installed app with label '%s'." % app_label)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'main'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 96, in apply_migration
    if self.detect_soft_applied(migration):
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 140, in detect_soft_applied
    apps = project_state.render()
  File "/Users/awwester/Sites/django/rlg/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 94, in render
    raise ValueError(msg.format(field=operations[0][1], model=lookup_model))
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field accounts.User.interests: main.Interest
```

Comment: Is the user class a subclass of model somehow?

Comment: nope, coming straight from the django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser

Comment: From django s reference : Think carefully before handling information not directly related to authentication in your custom User Model.

It may be better to store app-specific user information in a model that has a relation with the User model. That allows each app to specify its own user data requirements without risking conflicts with other apps. On the other hand, queries to retrieve this related information will involve a database join, which may have an effect on performance.

Comment: Read more about this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/